# Exam class: wrong \totalpoints

Tags: exam

I have a problem with the `exam` class. Almost all of my questions have parts and I intend to mention, not only the points given for each part, but also the points total at the beginning of the questions, like thus:

[image: What I want to do]

But for some questions (not all, strangely) the `\totalpoints` command doesn't give out the right points total, even if I compile many times. See what I mean:
[image: the problem]

The points total for this question is obviously 8, so why does it count 5 points? I first thought it had something to do with the `oneparcheckboxes` environment, as other questions whose total is wrong have such an environment inside them. But this one doesn't.

The code I used to customise the points appearance is

```
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\dots/\themarginpoints}
\qformat{\shadowbox{\thequestion}~\hrulefill ~\emph{\totalpoints\ points}}
```

Comment: Did you put the command "addpoints" in \doucmentclass[addpoints]{exam}?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Yes I did, that is why I'm surprised it doesn't work.